# Choosing between Densify vs Geodetic Densify tools

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

ArcGIS has both [Densify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/densify.htm) and [Geodetic Densify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/geodetic-densify.htm) tools. The help pages do not describe the tools well enough to determine when and where each is the most appropriate choice.

When and where should we use Geodetic Densify over Densify and vice versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Densify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/editing-toolbox/densify.htm)** - 2D Cartesian based on the data's coordinate system. It had better be projected, unless the data has a small extent (and possibly not at mid- to high-latitudes). It's fine for densifying lines or polygons for a city, county, or small state when the data is in a reasonable projected coordinate reference system. Never use it if the data is in a geographic coordinate reference system.

Use Densify when you want to maintain the "straightness" of the lines--like streets or parcel boundaries, things like that. It could include cases where you have lat/lon, but you want to densify along the latitude line--think the US-Canadian border in the west

**[Geodetic Densify](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/geodetic-densify.htm)** - Densifies on the ellipsoid surface using any of four options, so more accurate for larger extents or at mid- to high-latitudes. The calculations are performed on the ellipsoid associated with the input data's coordinate system.

Before and after `Densify` are the same rendered in pseudo-Plate Carree projection. The picture looks the same--straight line segments because the world is treated as if it's flat:

[image: straight line segments]

After `Geodetic Densify` the lines are curved when displayed in pseudo-Plate Carree:

[image: after geodetic densify]

*(pictures cropped from Esri help topic)*

Comment: Thank you. To clarify re: pictures: in the GD help page, the [first picture](https://i.imgur.com/T2Br0U3.png) shows the original shape. A `Densify` operation on that would increase the number of vertex points but the shape would remain unchanged when shown in pseudo-Plate Caree. Whereas `Geodetic Densify` would increase the number of points AND change the shape when drawn in pseudo Plate Caree, as shown in [2nd picture](https://i.imgur.com/vlpFzLw.png)?

Comment: The Silverlight API has a really good explanation of [Geodesic Densify](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/silverlight/apiref/ESRI.ArcGIS.Client~ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry.Geodesic~Densify.html), much better then the other help topics (mentions what ellipsoid is used for example). Do you know if this method is identical to the geoprocessing GD tool? (note `t` vs `s`)

Comment: Under the geodetic_type parameter: "Geodetic calculations are performed on the ellipsoid associated with the input data's coordinate system." They're likely both calling Esri projection engine in the end, but I'd have to run numbers because Silverlight is using "great circle" rather than "geodesic". Great circle means on a sphere, not an ellipsoid.

Comment: re: your first comment on the pictures. After Densify, the first picture would still look the same--straight line segments because the world is treated as if it's flat.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I see much more clearly now. Another way of asking the question: since Geodetic is so much smarter, shouldn't we just use it all the time? Are there situations where Densify is the better choice?

Comment: When you want to maintain the "straightness" of the lines--like streets or parcel boundaries, things like that. It could include cases where you have lat/lon, but you want to densify along the latitude line--think the US-Canadian border in the west...

Comment: I consildated comments into the answer -- @mkennedy please vet for completeness/accuracy/faithfulness; Roll back if you don't like it (I won't be offended)